# Создание контрола wpf

Tags: wpf

Создаю контрол в котором будут плавно прокручиваться картинки.

```
public partial class ImagesScroll : Canvas
    {
        private ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> _images;

        private DispatcherTimer _dispatcherTimer;
        public bool AnimationVector { get; set; }
        public int AnimationSpeed {
            private get { return 0; }
            set
            {
                if(value > 0)
                    _dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, value);
            }
        }
        public bool Run
        {
            get
            {
                return _dispatcherTimer.IsEnabled;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value)
                    _dispatcherTimer.Start();
                else
                    _dispatcherTimer.Stop();
            }
        }
        public void AddImages(string[] images)
        {
            if (_images == null)
                _images = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();

            foreach(var link in images)
            {
                try
                {
                    var imageSource = new BitmapImage();
                    imageSource.BeginInit();
                    imageSource.UriSource = new Uri(link);
                    imageSource.EndInit();

                    _images.Add(imageSource);
                }
                catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
                {
                    // log that the download was not successful
                }
            }
        }

        public ImagesScroll()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            _dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
            _dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);

            this.Refresh();
        }

        private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             this.InvalidateVisual();
        }

        int shift = 0;
        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
        {
           if (_images != null && _images.Count < 0)
                dc.DrawImage(_images[0], new Rect(0, 0, 320, 320));
            else {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                    {
                        var x = i * 160;
                        var y = j * 160 + shift;
                        dc.DrawRectangle(System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black, new System.Windows.Media.Pen(System.Windows.Media.Brushes.AliceBlue, 2), new Rect(x, y, 160, 160));
                    }
                }
            }

            shift -= 10;

            base.OnRender(dc);
        }
    }
}
```

Но возникла проблема, не работает перерисовка. Еще вопрос правильное решение этой задачи я выбрал?

Comment: А зачем вы переопределяете `OnRender`? Неужели стандартных анимаций недостаточно? Вы сами избрали наиболее сложный путь.

Comment: Я только в начале пути))) Что посоветуете в данной ситуации?

Comment: Нужно по мере добавления картинок прокручивать ленту

Comment: Ну, возьмите нормальную анимацию ([1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms752312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [2](https://habrahabr.ru/post/111126/)). Возможно, вам нужно будет подправить её параметры при добавлении новой картинки.